# Compute line integral $\int_a^b (y^2z^3dx + 2xyz^3dy + 3xy^2z^2dz)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Compute line integral $\int_a^b (y^2z^3dx + 2xyz^3dy + 3xy^2z^2dz)$ where $a = (1,1,1)$ and $b = (2,2,2)$

What I have done:

To find $t$ I used the calculation for slope:

$\frac{x-1}{2-1}=t, \frac{y-1}{2-1}=t, \frac{z-1}{2-1}=t$ and then re-arranged for x,y,z to calculate the derivate to find that $dx =1, dy=1, dz=1$ and $t+1 = (x, y, z)$

Plugging this back into the integral:
$$6\int_a^b (t+1)^5 dt$$

However, what do I do with the integral bounds? Do I set them from $t  \in [1,2]$?

Comment: The equality $t+1=(x,y,z)$ makes no sense.

Comment: What is the path of the integral? the line segment from $a$ to $b$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I was just trying to say that $t+1 = x, t+1 = y, t+1 = z$

Comment: @user I believe so; though the exercise doesn't explain much else besides this "Note that the field is the gradient field of a function easy to guess". Which isn't much help to me

Comment: Do you know how to check if a vector field is conservative, find potential function for a conservative vector field and then apply Fundamental Theorem of Line Integral?

Comment: See @user 's answer and also see this link: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/fundthmlineintegrals.aspx

Comment: @MathLover Kinda hard to piece everything as I just self-study. But I think that I get it now. A conservative vector field is same for all paths, one way of checking is if it has the same end-points?

Comment: A conservative vector field is one whose curl is zero i.e. $\nabla \times \vec F = 0$ and it is gradient of a scalar function. Then the line integral only depend on the start and end point.

Comment: @me.limes: if you study on your own, what book are you reading?

Comment: @user Currently reading multivariable mathematics by williamson. I have advanced engineering mathematics by Kreyzsig also but I'm only up to ODE's for that book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4292815/compute-line-integral-int-ab-y2z3dx-2xyz3dy-3xy2z2dz/4292824#comment8938860_4292815) you mentioned implies that you can use the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem). Note that
$$
(y^2z^3,2xyz^3,3xy^2z^2)=\nabla f(x,y,z)
$$
where $f(x,y,z)=xy^2z^3$. So the integral is path independent, and you don't really need to parametrize your path:
$$
\int_A^B \nabla f(x,y,z)\cdot dr=f(B)-f(A)
$$
where $A=(1,1,1)$, $B=(2,2,2)$.

Usually, the notation $\int_A^B$ is only used for path integrals that are path independent. Otherwise, one usually uses $\int_\gamma$ instead and describes $\gamma$ in words.

Comment: To OP, while in this case it is straightforward but the steps would be to first check if the curl is zero then integrate to find potential function and then apply fundamental theorem of line integral.

Comment: @MathLover I haven't thought about that before. The curl is when I take the determinant of the partial derivatives in respect to x,y,z, right?  What's the potential function? the method used by user?

Comment: @me.limes Yes it is calculated using cross product of the vector field with the del (nabla) operator (partial derivative operator). The potential function is the scalar function whose gradient is the vector field.

Comment: The subtle point to note is this - the question does not state the path from $(1, 1, 1)$ to $(2, 2, 2)$. It does not state the path is a straight line which you have assumed in your work. It could be any smooth curve. So the correct way to go about it is to apply fundamental theorem of line integral.

Comment: @me.limes: You simply use "gradient field of a function" in your exercise's hint. The notion of "potential function" is mostly used in physics.

Comment: @MathLover: regarding paths, please read the last paragraph.

Comment: yes that's really my point to OP. The question does not give a specific path which OP has assumed in their work. Sorry for the confusion. My last comment was to be addressed to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(x,y,z)=(t+1,t+1,t+1)$ and you want to go from $(1,1,1)$ to $(2,2,2)$, you should compute that integral with $a=0$ and $b=1$.

Note that talking about $\int_a^b(y^2z^3\,\mathrm dx+2xyz^3\,\mathrm dy+3xy^2z^2\,\mathrm dz)$ only makes sense because your vector field is conservative. Otherwise, the integral would depend upon the path going from $(1,1,1)$ to $(2,2,2)$.

Comment: How did you distinguish $a = 0$ and $b=1$ from $x, y, z$?

Comment: I don't know what that means. All I did was to compute the integral along the path$$\begin{array}{rccc}\gamma\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^3\\&t&\mapsto&(t+1,t+1,t+1).\end{array}$$